# How to add a delete button to my dialog?

Tags: android, database, button

I have a Add Contact App which in some part, it shows the contacts already registered so when you click it it shows (Name and Telephone number) and a OK Button, so I want to add a Delete button to delete its value (delete the contact value from the database) from the dialog.
Here are the codes:

ListView for the contacts:

```
   ListView user = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvShowContatos);
    //String = simple value ||| String[] = multiple values/columns
    String[] campos = new String[] {"nome", "telefone"};

    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    c = db.query( "contatos", campos, null, null, null, null, null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    String lista = "";
    if(c.getCount() > 0) {
        while(true) {
           list.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("nome")).toString());
            if(!c.moveToNext()) break;
        }
    }

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

    user.setAdapter(adapter);

    user.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            c.moveToPosition(position);
            String nome = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("nome"));
            String telefone = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("telefone"));
            ShowMessage(nome, telefone);
        }
    });
```

And there is the "ShowMessage" code which is the Dialog that shows up:

```
       public void ShowMessage(String titulo,String msg){
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);        
    dialogo.setMessage(msg);        
    dialogo.setTitle(titulo);
    dialogo.setNeutralButton("OK", null);       
    dialogo.show();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dialogo.setNegativeButton("Delete", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //delete contact or what you want.
               }
           });
```

or as on your code :

```
dialogo.setNegativeButton("Delete", null);
```

Read more on http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: delete contact code: `db.delete("contatos", "nome='"+nome+"' and telefone='" + telefone +"'", null);`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a **Custom Dialog** as described here in the documentation here

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html